# Android studio suddenly started showing gradle error

Tags: android-studio

No cache version of com.android.tools.build: gradle:3.1.3 available for offline mode
My gradle:

```
dependencies{
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn on gradle and rebuild application, in order to do this:

File-->Settings -->Build, Executions, Deployment --> Build Tools --> Gradle --> uncheck the "offline work" --> click on the apply button --> rebuild your application